# How to set up a specific seedvalue in gds.beta.node2vec.write?

Tags: neo4j, graph-theory

I'm running node2vec in neo4j but when the algorithm runs again with the same parameters, the result changes. So, I read the configuration and I see that there is a seedvalue.
I tried to set the seedvalue in a specific number, but nothing changes..

https://github.com/aditya-grover/node2vec/issues/83

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the documentation you can see that the `randomSeed` parameters is available. However, the results are still non-deterministic as per the docs:

> Seed value used to generate the random walks, which are used as the
> training set of the neural network. Note, that the generated
> embeddings are still nondeterministic.

Comment: is there a way to see the exact seed that the algorithm uses?

Comment: then the seedvalue parameter is useless... @Tomaž Bratanič